# Windows 8 won't resume from sleep

Tags: windows-8, sleep

I upgraded to Win 8 from 7, not through a fresh install and some months now I've noticed that I can't wake up my computer by any means except by pressing the on/off button.
After researching extensively on line, I still can't find a solution.
Please note that this issue was not present with Win 7
I'd appreciate your guidance.

Arturo

Comment: Could you kindly tell us what you have done?  Checked BIOS, checked Advanced Power Settings, checked Event logs?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Windows Tools Menu and launch Device Manager.

[image]

Right click on your keyboard and open it's properties.

[image]

Switch to Power Management tab and select allow this device to wake the computer checkbox.

[image]

Repeat for mouse.

Comment: Neat wake-up idea.